# How to sort a std::map by ascending order of value?

Tags: c++, sorting, stdmap

I'm trying to figure out how to sort `std::map` by ascending order of value.

**My Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

void printMapByOrder(std::map<std::string, int> mapOfPlanets)
{
    //what should be here?
}

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, int> mapOfPlanets;
    mapOfPlanets["earth"] = 12;
    mapOfPlanets["jupiter"] = 142;
    mapOfPlanets["mars"] = 6;
    mapOfPlanets["mercury"] = 4;
    mapOfPlanets["neptune"] = 49;
    mapOfPlanets["pluto"] = 2;
    mapOfPlanets["saturn"] = 120;
    mapOfPlanets["uranus"] = 51;
    mapOfPlanets["venus"] = 12;
    printMapByOrder(mapOfPlanets);
}
```

**The Result I want :**

```
 pluto : 2
 mercury : 4
 mars : 6
 earth : 12
 venus : 12
 neptune : 49
 uranus : 51
 saturn : 120
 jupiter : 142
```

Is this possible to do this with `std::map`?

Comment: do you want to sort the map in ascending order (what your text says and what the dupe is about) or do you want to sort the map descending and only print its elements in ascending order (what your code suggests)

Comment: @user463035818 I want to sort the map in ascending order like my text and code suggests.

Comment: well the code suggests something different, otherwise the "//what should be here" is in the wrong place. Printing elements of a map in order is the same no matter how they are sorted. Nevermind, the dupe has the answer for you

Comment: The suggested dupe was wrong. This question is about sorting the values not the keys.

Comment: @ZackLee One simple answer is to copy the map elements into a vector and sort the vector. Then print the vector.

Comment: @john Thank you but I would like to know more performant solution since this will be called every frame.

Comment: @ZackLee Sounds like you are looking for something like this, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html

Comment: Sorting a vector with `std::sort` and a predicate IS the better performing solution. How many entries are we talking about? For a dozen, it won’t matter what you do. First benchmark, then worry about performance.

Comment: Can't you use a `set` of  `pair`s?

Comment: @cristid9 the map would be sorted with respect to the `pair` as a whole, not the keys and values separately.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Usually from 100 to 500 entries will be used.

Comment: So that’s a few kilobytes of RAM. I would start with whatever is easier to code and understand and then work from there. Benchmarking will tell you what’s fast enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::map` is ordered by its *keys*, and that can't be changed (after all, the point of a map is *fast access by key*).  You could, however, create a container of pointers to your map elements, and sort that for printing.  You'll want to pass your map by const reference, so that your pointers won't be invalidated:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

void printMapByOrder(const std::map<std::string, int>& mapOfPlanets)
{
    using element = typename std::map<std::string, int>::value_type;
    std::vector<const element*> sorted;
    sorted.reserve(mapOfPlanets.size());
    for (auto& planet: mapOfPlanets)
        sorted.push_back(&planet);

    # sort by value
    std::sort(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(),
              [](auto *a, auto *b) {
                  return std::tie(a->second, a->first)
                      <  std::tie(b->second, b->first);
              });

    # print results
    std::transform(sorted.begin(), sorted.end(),
                   std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout),
                   [](const auto *p) {
                       return p->first + ": "
                           + std::to_string(p->second) + '\n';
                   });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. Its not possible to sort a map by its values.

One possible solution:

```
void printMapByOrder(std::map<std::string, int> mapOfPlanets)
{
    std::vector < std::pair<std::string, int> > planets(mapOfPlanets.begin(), mapOfPlanets.end());
    std::sort(planets.begin(), planets.end(), [](auto lhs, auto rhs) {return lhs.second < rhs.second; });
    //print planets
}
```